# Jumping to a specific PDF page in EDGE browser

Tags: html, pdf, microsoft-edge

I'm linking directly to pages within a PDF document using the #page=xx format. E.g.

```
<a href="mydocument.pdf#page=12">Link here</a>
```

This works in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but not in EDGE. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hello, Phil. I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Edge web-platform team, and see the issue to which you are referring. I've reached out to a contact on the app-side of Edge, and hope to hear back regarding our support of this feature.

Comment: Thanks Sampson, that's great that it's being looked into. I look forward to any updates.

Comment: @Sampson: any news on that topic? (I just tried with the latest Edge and it does not work yet.)

Answer (score 1):

The question was dated at the time of New Edge prior to shift to Chromium.

With Chromium based Edge this was supported by the Chromium PDF extender and should work for most Current Edge users. Will work on web and local, here I ask for page 5
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" "file://C:\Apps\PDF\GS\gs1000w64\bin\out.pdf#page=5"`
and get page 5
[image]

**HOWEVER :-**

Edge has an ON/OFF  feature to re-open a document at last page viewed, which can naturally block a #page=## request if its toggled as ON.
[image]

I have had mixed results when using the Acrobat Plug-in activated in Edge Browser when there is also the in-built Chromium Viewer, and **the whole situation is about to change** this coming year from March 2023 to March 2024 as Edge is shifting back to an Adobe based subscription enhanced viewer !! So this answer *may* become outdated, in a few weeks !

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10454778/ and the user Jan O it could be possible in version 42.17074.1000.0, but then James C writes that it "semi works". I haven't been able to try it yet.

Comment: Your link is dead.  It looks like the #page=xx works, but only for pdfs opened as URIs (http://www.dom.com/help.pdf#page=3).  There appears to be no way to open a local file system based PDF with a #page=xx target.  This is not good, as it makes Edge's support for use in offline help systems, for example, unworkable.  Edge badly needs this.  Named PDF destination support, even via web URIs in Edge, is non-existant at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by KJ is helpful, but beware, if you have tried to annotate a PDF using Edge's annotation tools in browser, save the PDF with its annotations BEFORE switching to a page number using this method, as it will load the file from the file system unchanged, otherwise.