# How can I programmatically open a pdf at first page using Edge Browser and Acrobat PDF .pdf#page= URL fragment?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge, acrobat

I have tried **[www.myexample.pfd#page=1](http://www.myexample.pfd#page=1)** but does not work. When I tried other pages it works fine but except on page 1 of the pdf.

Comment: related question and possibly a dup target: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38187449/11107541 (unless the way to open allows specifying a page whereas jumping after opening is not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like many browser commands down to user setting.

Here I asked for page 1 and get page 2 because I was viewing page 2 last time
[image]

If I change this setting to off
[image]

Then I can expect page 1

[image]

To see how this works try these two links RIGHT CLICK open new window should with above setting remember page 2 and thus NOT open Page 1 in second window

https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2
https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1

A secondary problem is Edge may also resist reloading the same file

### Answer

Based on the answer I got from Yu Zhou https://stackoverflow.com/a/74609539/10802527 **this usually works.**

So try something like this for page 1 this should work by treating the file as if a different one.

https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf?p=1#page=1
[image]